# angularjs data-ui-sref reload not working?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I am using angular form builder and UI-Router. How can I set the reload option?

```
<a data-ui-sref="app.fbforms.newfbform" 
   data-ui-sref-opts="{cache: false,reload:true}">NewForm</a>
```

> not working reload option.. page not properly load

Answer (score 2):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3WrJYrmksYTfxvOvhiMF?p=preview). The link defined as above is working AS IS. The issue must be elsewhere.

So, to prove it, I created these states:

```
  .state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      template: '<div ui-view></div>',
  })
  .state('app.fbforms', {
      url: '/fbforms',
      template: '<div ui-view></div>',
  })
  .state('app.fbforms.newfbform', { 
      url: "/newfbform",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: 'newfbformCtrl',
  })
```

and this controller

```
.controller('newfbformCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
  $scope.now = new Date();
}])
```

And this call is working as expected:

```
<a data-ui-sref="app.fbforms.newfbform" 
   data-ui-sref-opts="{cache: false,reload:true}">
```

And changes this view on every click:

```
<div>
  changes on reload: {{now}}
</div>
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3WrJYrmksYTfxvOvhiMF?p=preview)

Comment: can u help me?   @Radim

Comment: I definitely want, to help you. Your expected link is correct. I created a plunker with **full example**. Please check it. That could help you to see what is my setting and compare it with yours. The point is - concept is correct ;) And if that won't help - **sugestion** please change my plunker to broken state. I will gladly assist to fix it.. ok? make sense?